# Xcode 4: Update CFBundleVersion on each build using Git repo commit version

Tags: xcode, git

I'm using Xcode 4 in combination with Git and would like to increment the CFBundleVersion in Info.plist on each build. The value for the key CFBundleVersion should be updated to the number of the last commit I made to the Git repository.

I found [that](http://valthonis.net/2011/05/16/unique-build-numbers-for-xcode-4/) python script which works well, but unfortunately doesn't update the Info.plist in my Xcode project - it just updates the Info.plist in the "BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR".

Does anyone has an idea how to get Xcode 4 to fetch the version of the latest commit and put that information into the project's Info.plist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version string needs to be of the format [xx].[yy].[zz] where x, y, z are numbers.

I deal with this by using `git tag` to give specific commits meaningful tag numbers for x and y (eg 0.4), and then via a script build phase, z gets the number of commits since the last tag, as returned by `git describe`.

Here's the script, which I adapted from [this one](http://heipei.net/2009/02/23/xcode-git-describe-in-your-infoplist/). It can be added straight to the target as a build phase (`shell` is `/usr/bin/env ruby`):

```
# add git tag + version number to Info.plist
version = `/usr/bin/env git describe`.chomp

puts "raw version "+version
version_fancy_re = /(\d*\.\d*)-?(\d*)-?/
version =~ version_fancy_re
commit_num = $2
if ( $2.empty? )
commit_num = "0"
end
fancy_version = ""+$1+"."+commit_num
puts "compatible: "+fancy_version

# backup
source_plist_path = File.join(ENV['PROJECT_DIR'], ENV['INFOPLIST_FILE'])
orig_plist = File.open( source_plist_path, "r").read;
File.open( source_plist_path+".bak", "w") { |file| file.write(orig_plist) }

# put in CFBundleVersion key
version_re = /([\t ]+<key>CFBundleVersion<\/key>\n[\t ]+<string>).*?(<\/string>)/
orig_plist =~ version_re
bundle_version_string = $1 + fancy_version + $2
orig_plist.gsub!(version_re, bundle_version_string)

# put in CFBundleShortVersionString key
version_re = /([\t ]+<key>CFBundleShortVersionString<\/key>\n[\t ]+<string>).*?(<\/string>)/
orig_plist =~ version_re
bundle_version_string = $1 + fancy_version + $2
orig_plist.gsub!(version_re, bundle_version_string)

# write
File.open(source_plist_path, "w") { |file| file.write(orig_plist) }
puts "Set version string to '#{fancy_version}'"
```

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly for me

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
    begin
        require 'Plist'
        rescue LoadError => e
        puts "You need to install the 'Plist' gem: [sudo] gem install plist"
    exit 1
end

raise "Must be run from Xcode" unless ENV['XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL']

GIT = "/usr/bin/env git"
PRODUCT_PLIST = File.join(ENV['BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR'], ENV['INFOPLIST_PATH'])
HASH = `#{GIT} log -1 --pretty=format:%h`
BUNDLE_VERSION = "CFBundleVersion"

if File.file?(PRODUCT_PLIST) and HASH

    # update product plist
    `/usr/bin/plutil -convert xml1 \"#{PRODUCT_PLIST}\"`
    info = Plist::parse_xml(PRODUCT_PLIST)
    if info
        info[BUNDLE_VERSION] = HASH
        info["GCGitCommitHash"] = HASH
        info.save_plist(PRODUCT_PLIST)
    end
    `/usr/bin/plutil -convert binary1 \"#{PRODUCT_PLIST}\"`

    # log
    puts "updated #{BUNDLE_VERSION} to #{HASH}"
    puts "HEAD: #{HASH}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

@damian Thank you for the script it works well.

But after then I had following problem. Every time after a commit when I build the project then I have changes in git. I had the solution to ignore the plist file but I don't want that.

Now I add your script into pre-commit hook in git instead of xcode build phase. The only problem with that is my script can not get PROJECT_DIR and INFOPLIST_FILE so I had to write them hard coded in scipt. I could not find how to get the env variables from a xcode project.

It works well :)

Comment: What you might want to do is to put your plist as a template into your repo, ignore the actual plist in your repo, and then generate it on build-time. That way, you do not have auto-generated stuff in the repository.