# iPad application version?

Tags: ios, version

what is the version value that one is supposed to use to identify a build in the field?  I was thinking that it is the value from the main bundle if one were to code the following:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey: @"CFBundleVersion"];
```

Is this correct?  Can this be set by an automated build script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a version number to be set by the developer such as 1.0.1 and needs to be incremented when new versions are compiled.  You can populate this number using a source code control system such as subversion, or you can manage the version number yourself.

Here's another solution:

[Xcode 4: Update CFBundleVersion on each build using Git repo commit version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317181/xcode-4-update-cfbundleversion-on-each-build-using-git-repo-commit-version)