# Using git tag for app version number without commit squashing?

Tags: xcode, git

There's lots of questions (and answers) on this already in SO, but none seem to address this specific point, or I'm just not understanding the process.  Typical development process, ending in:

1. Final code fixes & testing
2. Commit to Git
3. Tag commit with version number
4. Run script that updates Info.plist with version and build number
5. ????

I run step 4 in the Post-Archive build step, so the plist gets updated and my distribution archive is created.  Works great, except...

The snapshot that I committed and tagged isn't the one with the updated Info.plist with the correct version information in it.  It's a catch-22.  I can't commit until I have the plist updated, but I can't update the plist until I have a tagged commit.

Yeah, I can squash commit the changed plist back into the commit after, and then re-tag, but that's certainly not automated and it's error prone.

Maybe I should be doing this in a pre- or post-commit hook instead?  Or is my process wrong?

Edit:  This question is specifically about using Git with Xcode, and best practices in that specific environment.   I guess just putting the Xcode tag on the question wasn't enough.

Comment: Why not simply create the tag after updating your Info.plist? I'm not sure I understand the problem.

Comment: Currently, the version number (and tag) depends on the commit.  That is, the script generates the version number, which goes into the info.plist, from the tag, which is already on a commit.

Comment: Looks like http://stackoverflow.com/a/11899540/177415 asks the same question, but I didn't really understand the reply.

Comment: Do you mean the version number you are storing in Info.plist depends on the actual value of the SHA1 commit id from Git? Yeah, you're not going to be able to store that in Info.plist *and* tag with the same value. Not even with squashing commits.

Comment: No, it's not dependent on the SHA1 ID, but it does require that a commit (and tag) already exist.  I think what you're suggesting is to manually edit the Info.plist with the new version number, then do the commit, then tag that commit.  Seems error prone to me.

Comment: You could write a script to automate the work of updating the version number in Info.plist. When I release something, there's one commit at the end where the only thing changed is the release number, and I tag that commit.

Comment: Do you update your Info.plist automatically?  What's the new version number based on, if you don't use a tag in the repository?

Comment: I decide what the next version number is manually. For example, a bug fix after 1.2.3 would be 1.2.4. I put that in the Info.plist, commit, and tag with a `version-1.2.4` tag.

Comment: OK, so you don't have an automated solution.  Fair enough.  Maybe someone else will.

Comment: I didn't say that. For some projects I do have a script that automatically does all three of those actions. I run it like `update-version 1.2.4` and it takes care of the details.

Comment: Then maybe you could post that script as an answer?

Comment: You say "The snapshot that I committed and tagged isn't the one with the updated Info.plist with the correct version information in it." That makes it sound like Info.plist is *in* the commit, but has the wrong version in it, because you can't know the version until after you've made the commit. That, in turn, makes it sound like the version is dependent on the SHA-1. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but if each is dependent on the other, then it's hard to imagine how the SHA-1 isn't coming into play.

Comment: I suppose I can imagine a system that looks at your git history and doles out a version number when it sees a new commit. You might want that in the commit itself, but it's not possible if it's tied to the SHA-1. If it's not tied to the SHA-1, but for some other reason you can't get the version number until you commit, then you could take the version number, update the file, then do a `commit --amend` to fold the new number back in. That will change the SHA-1 of the commit, though, but if that's not part of it, it could work. Then you could tag that ammended commit with the same number.

Comment: Do an SO search on xcode, git, and version numbers.  There are dozens of Q&A about using git describe in scripts to generate version numbers.  The most common ones are based on tags and number of commits s since the last tag.  So it's not the SHA-1, but it is the state of the repository.  Adding the commit changes the version number.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store the version number as a literal in the Info.plist. Use the Info.plist that's in your repository as a template and have the build process generate the actual Info.plist in the built app from it. This is actually the default, with build settings like `PRODUCT_NAME`, `EXECUTABLE_NAME`, etc. substituted into the file during build.

So, the version number should be computed from the state of the repository during every build. This raises a complication, which is that Xcode needs to be forced to generate the built Info.plist from the template even if the modification time of the template file hasn't changed.

I recommend that you rename Info.plist in your repository to Info.plist.in or something and then use a run-script build phase to generate Info.plist from Info.plist.in. As I suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730186/how-do-i-force-xcode-to-rebuild-the-info-plist-file-in-my-project-every-time-i-b/16287164#16287164), you can use a separate target to do that. This target would be added as a dependency of the target that builds the app so Xcode is sure to build it first. The target to generate the Info.plist would be a shell script target containing just the run-script build phase. If you don't set the inputs of a run-script build phase, Xcode runs it unconditionally.